# Parsing JSON files line by line

Tags: python, json, parsing

How can you parse a large file containing many (single) lines of JSON objects without storing each line in a list for efficiency?

Answer (score 0):

Would:

```
fp = open("file")
for i, line in enumerate(fp):
    #  reads only i+1th line

    # or if you just need the 26th line
    if i == 25:
         print line


fp.close()
```

help? This saves you having to load the whole file into memory at once, and instead only reads each line at a time.